# How to jump through the window during "Ghost Town" quest?

Tags: cyberpunk-2077

I am supposed to jump through a windows after breaking the glass, yet I cannot and when I try I get teleported hundreds meters away due to a bug. How can I enter the building? (I know there is a door, but it requires 8 body and I only have 3.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take out a knive (or gun) and remove the remaining glass at the edges of the window. Once you cleared the glass remains at the frame enough, you can jump through the window without issues.

Answer (score 3):

I found that is helps if you're moving when you jump - run and jump at the window and you should have better success than trying it from a standstill. One of the tooltips during loading actually mentions something about vaulting over objects while moving, so I suspect this might not work from a complete standstill.

Note there is a weird bug in this location as well, where failed attempts to jump through the window will randomly throw you a few hundred meters backwards. This shouldn't kill you and you can just run back to the window and try again.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. But I realized that I was holding a weapon. Once I holstered my weapon so that my hands were free, I was able to jump through the window with no problem!